# php - Quebra de linha em array

Tags: php

Estou querendo pular linha em uma tabela, mas não consigo arranjar uma lógica para fazer isso. Já tentei o explode e não obtive sucesso.

```
<td><?=$teste['cod_refugo_teste'];?></td>
<td><?=$teste['qtd_refugo']; ?></td>
```

O código fica assim: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero que as linhas de refugo e quantidade se quebrem, mas não acho um jeito de fazê-lo.

Comment: Está a utilizar o datatable?

Comment: Tenta assim...
`<td><?=$teste['cod_refugo_teste'];."</br>".$teste['qtd_refugo']; ?></td>`

Comment: Poste sua estrutura html da tabela. Isso é questão da tabela, não do php

Comment: Veja: https://jsfiddle.net/mgd2b75p/6

Comment: Marcelo, o problema é que eu estarei pulando os arrays cod_refugo_teste e qtd_refugo. Quero que pule a linha a cada refugo e a cada quantidade, entende?

Comment: Quando diz pular a linha é deixar os campos todos a branco menos o refugo e quantidade ? Acho que seria mais claro se colocasse um exemplo do como esperava que ficasse.

Comment: Sem um exemplo fica muito confuso o que você realmente precisa.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa utilizar o atributo **rowspan** na tag .

Veja este exemplo,apresenta exatamente o comportamento que você deseja:
https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_td_rowspan.asp

Answer (score -1):

Silvia, nesse caso seria mais interessante ver seu código completo para entender o que está dentro da variável `$teste`.

A tag HTML para pular linhas é a `<tr></tr>` que cria uma nova linha. A cada linha nova, deve ser adicionado um `<tr></tr>`.

Caso os valores da variável `$teste` estejam em um array, você pode criar uma função de loop, como o `for`, como por exemplo:

```
<?php

$valores = [
    'produto1',
    'quantidade1',
    'responsavel1',
    'data1',
    'produto1',
    'quantidade2',
    'responsavel2',
    'data2'
];

$html = "";

for ($n = 0 ; $n < count($valores) ; $n++) {
    if ($n % 3 == 0 || $n == 0)
        html += "<tr>";

    html += $valores[$n];

    if($n % 3 == 0 || $n == 0)
        html += "</tr>";
}
```